# How do I add an object from one project to another?

Tags: game-engine

I'm trying to add a tree for my game in a forest and they are in separate files. How can I get the tree into my game? I have already tried appending and linking but I want the entire thing. Even what I did all it did nothing.

Comment: Appending/linking is exactly what you need, could you explain what the Problem was? (In most cases you would want to create a Group, and then link that Group.)

Comment: Is every tree in a seperate blend file? Otherwise when you set up a sence with the forest you can append that and choose the scene as the target to append. Or give more information.

Comment: put a screenshot of your files and explain what you did and what you expected will result from it